# Why does fdisk and parted not show same partition table on a fresh bootable usb image

Tags: boot, partitioning, fdisk, parted

I follow the instruction on https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu except I use a SD-card to flash.

When I use `fdisk` and `parted` to investigate the result of the flashed SD-card I get two very different results. Both results are very weird:

```
jarl@hermes:~$ sudo LANG=C fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 1.9 GiB, 2032664576 bytes, 3970048 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x133f436e

Device         Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *          0 3905279 3905280  1.9G  0 Empty
/dev/mmcblk0p2      3828884 3833811    4928  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

```
jarl@hermes:~$ sudo LANG=C parted /dev/mmcblk0
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/mmcblk0
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit                                                             
Unit?  [compact]? b                                                       
(parted) print                                                            
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel? I                                                          
Model: SD SD02G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 8130658304B
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/512B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start        End          Size      File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B        6143B        4096B                  Apple
 2      1960388608B  1962911743B  2523136B               EFI

(parted) q
```

1. `parted` gives a warning (that I don't understand) that fdisk doesn't. Any explanation?
2. `fdisk` shows that partition 2 (the EFI one) starts in the middle of partition 1 (ISO image)
3. `parted` seem not to show the correct start and end of partition 1
4. `parted` seem not to show the correct end of partition 2

Can anyone explain the above differences? I belive that `parted` is quite buggy, and that `fdisk` information is correct, but then again it shows overlapping partitions.

Comment: I do not think you are seeing standard partitions. Most of the installers now use dd or dd under  the hood to create flash drive installers. And that is a hybrid DVD/flash drive image, not a standard partitioned drive with installer. If you have and only want UEFI you can create your own. UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formatted flash drive partition & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media
If you want to reuse flash drive: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive

Comment: Thank you @oldfred. Very informative answer. Thank you very much for the links